# how to put image in center of html page?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to center div horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296015/how-to-center-div-horizontally-and-vertically)

I need to put image in center of html page, both vertical and horizontal ... been trying few stuff but seems to work fine. To get horizontal alignment I used 
`<body style="text-align:center">`

and it works fine, but what do with vertical alignment?

regards

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been answered more than few times in here already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296015/how-to-center-div-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: Here's an example that works in IE7 (if it matters), unlike the usual `display: table-cell` answers, and with an image of unknown dimensions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998614/ie7-vertically-align-middle-not-working/10998683#10998683

Comment: before asking questions just give 2 or 3 mints to SO or www.google.com

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If:

> X is image width,
>   Y is image height,

then:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -(X/2)px;
    margin-top: -(Y/2)px;
}
```

But keep in mind this solution is valid only if the only element on your site will be this image. I suppose that's the case here.

Using this method gives you the benefit of fluidity. It won't matter how big (or small) someone's screen is. The image will always stay in the middle.

Comment: where is X in this code???

Comment: If you don't know the size of the image, then just replace `margin-left` and `margin-top` lines with this: `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Answer (score 9):

Put your image in a container div then use the following CSS (changing the dimensions to suit your image.

```
.imageContainer{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px; /*the image width*/
        height: 100px; /*the image height*/
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: -50px; /*half the image width*/
        margin-top: -50px; /*half the image height*/
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey now you can give to **body background image**

and set the `background-position:center center;`

as like this

```
body{
background:url('../img/some.jpg') no-repeat center center;
min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different options, based on what exactly the effect you're going for is. Chris Coyier did a piece on just this way back when. Worth a read:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/