# Centering the content of a row on large screens (> 1920px)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried many solutions posted on the web and none seem to solve my problem when the width goes larger than 1920 px. The things I have tried include, but not limited to:

- http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html
- [How to center image in a div horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296015/how-to-center-image-in-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically)
- [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

I have even tried the good old trick of wrapping the `div` in a text element and just aligning it to center but it was no good. Before I move on to code here are some pictures to visualize the problem. 
Here is how it looks like when width <= 1920px (ignore the minor alignment issues on bottom of the page)

[image]

And here is what happens when I expand the screen. Everything except that row aligns perfectly.

[image]

***Relevant Code:***

**HTML:**

```
<div class="displaylayer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                <img src="images/button2.png" class="clickthisleft" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-7"> 
                <div id="displayframe">
                    <div id="display">
                        <img id="mainimage" src="images/col1.jpg" height="420" width="960" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                <img src="images/button2.png" class="clickthisrigth"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .container{
   width: 100%;
 }
 .row{
   width: 100%;
 }
 .displaylayer {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }

 .displaylayer .row div{
    margin-left: 5%;
  }

  #display{
     width: 960px;
     height: 420px;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin-left: 0%;
     margin-right: auto;
     border-radius: 4px;
     background-color: white;
  }

 .displaylayer .container{
    width: 100%;
 }

 .displaylayer .row{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 200px; 
 }
 .clickthisleft, .clickthisrigth{
     margin-top: 130px;
     width: 70px;
     height: 200px;
  }

  .clickthisrigth{
     margin-left: 45%;
   }

 .clickthisleft{
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Even if it takes to up to a certain width, I can manually arrange for the rest. Every automated pixel means less manual optimization which is always good.

Comment: how about adding `class="img-responsive"` in you image?

Comment: Tried it right now. Doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the sum of the values of the scaffolding classes (`col-md-* col-lg-*`) must be equal to 12 [Bootstrap grid example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) so try to change the HTML to this:

```
<div class="displaylayer">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/button2.png" class="clickthisleft" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10"> 
            <div id="displayframe">
                <div id="display">
                    <img id="mainimage" src="images/col1.jpg" height="420" width="960" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/button2.png" class="clickthisrigth"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or try with different values but must sum up to 12.

Comment: You guys are awesome. I actually never thought about this (didnt know they had to sum up either) . Thanks you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Currently your columns don't take up the full 12-column width of Bootstrap. Each column is floated left, so they will align to the left. You want to add an offset to your middle column to force it in the middle.

For example, 12 - 1 - 1 - 7 = 3 columns left. You want to split that, so if you add a `col-lg-offset-1` on the 7-column middle section, then it will be one column closer to the center. That won't be perfect, however, and unfortunately you currently can't divide by half a column.

Your best bet would be to make the middle column 8 wide, and keep that 1 column offset (or equivalently, make it 10 columns wide and don't have the offset). Each div inside will be `display: block`, which means it takes up the full width. Images are `display: inline` by default, so you can force them to the center:

```
#display {
    #mainimage: {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

`text-align` applies to `inline` and `inline-block` *children*, so it's important to apply it to the parent of the image (and to keep the image as `inline` or `inline-block`).

Comment: This works. Only the code you provided modifies the slider but I didnt know it had to add up to 12 (I can only pick one answer so I just did first come first serve but this works perfectly) Thank you so much. For arranging position I can deal with that with margin properties I think =)